# Why do some car's A-engine-mounts have bolts vs studs vs both?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical, bolting

I have come across engine mounts of various cars and am just curious primarily related to the **"A" engine mounts** where some manufacturers use only **BOLTS**, while some use only **STUDS** and some use a combination of **BOLTS and STUDS**.

Any idea why they use BOLTS or STUDS or a combination of both? Why not stick to just BOLTS or just STUDS?

For example:

**Jeep Compass**, uses all bolts:
[image]

**Tata Nexon petrol engine**, uses all studs:
[image]

**Tata Nexon diesel engine**, uses all bolts:
[image]

**Maruti Suzuki Brezza**, uses two studs and one bolt:
[image]

**Hyundai Venue**, uses two studs and one bolt:
[image]

Comment: that seems like a question that should be asked of the person that made the choice in the final design ... the reason may be related to any number of factors

Comment: Always one reason for anything mass produced: someone believed it to be cost-effective overall. That overall cost includes not just costs of parts being joined, but also what was already built/analyzed up to that point, costs of delaying to make a change, etc. Ultimately it must have reached a point where it was not worth changing.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a consequence of access and being able to remove and replace the mount.

Also studs can be chosen as they can be designed to locate at the same time, but separate pins can be used.

Comment: Don't studs have better-tightening torque-abiity as there is only vertical stretch while in the case of a bolt vertical and rotational stretch resulting in more tightening torque errors?

Comment: Some bolts are designed to stretch more than others, and the "stretch' or elongation is usually calculated for and designed into the fixing, especially for head bolts and studs. Many are one-use and need to be replaced once removed, however many "cheap" mechanics and cowboys don't bother...

Answer (score 1):

Studs need four operations, drill and tap hole, insert stud, tighten nut. Bolt needs only three. As you can see from the Jeep you need less clearance for the gun on a bolt if you use a modern head design. I dare say someone somewhere is using threadforming bolts rather than tapping the hole.